# Generate multiple cross joins with Postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSON array containing objects with two members named `first` and `second`. Each one has a value array. I would like to generate the rows with all possible combinations between the values in `first` with the values in `second` for one given object and then do the same with the next one, and so on. There can be any number of objects. Some of the values in the arrays could be identical.

Example 1:

```json
[{"first":["1 - one", "2 - two", "3 - three"], "second": [1, 2]}]
```

should give me

```
   first   | second
-----------+--------
 1 - one   |      1
 1 - one   |      2
 2 - two   |      1
 2 - two   |      2
 3 - three |      1
 3 - three |      2
(6 rows)
```

Example 2:

```json
[
 {"first":["1 - one", "2 - two", "3 - three"], "second": [1, 2]},
 {"first":["4 - four", "5 - five"], "second": [10]}
]
```

should give me

```
   first   | second
-----------+--------
 1 - one   |      1
 1 - one   |      2
 2 - two   |      1
 2 - two   |      2
 3 - three |      1
 3 - three |      2
 4 - four  |     10
 5 - five  |     10
(8 rows)
```

When there is only one object, the following query is working well.

```sql
with t1(j) as (
  select jsonb_array_elements('[{"first":["1 - one", "2 - two", "3 - three"], "second": [1, 2]}]'::jsonb)
),
t2(first, second) as (
  select * from
    (select jsonb_array_elements_text(j->'first') from t1) as first
    cross join
    (select jsonb_array_elements_text(j->'second')::smallint from t1) as second
)
select * from t2 order by first, second;
```

Of course the same query with multiple objects doesn't work since it is doing a `cross join` between all the values of `first` and `second` instead of respecting the pairs.

```sql
with t1(j) as (
  select jsonb_array_elements('[{"first":["1 - one", "2 - two", "3 - three"], "second": [1, 2]},{"first":["4 - four", "5 - five"], "second": [10]}]'::jsonb)
),
t2(first, second) as (
  select * from
    (select jsonb_array_elements_text(j->'first') from t1) as first
    cross join
    (select jsonb_array_elements_text(j->'second')::smallint from t1) as second
)
select * from t2 order by first, second;
```

```
   first   | second
-----------+--------
 1 - one   |      1
 1 - one   |      2
 1 - one   |     10
 2 - two   |      1
 2 - two   |      2
 2 - two   |     10
 3 - three |      1
 3 - three |      2
 3 - three |     10
 4 - four  |      1
 4 - four  |      2
 4 - four  |     10
 5 - five  |      1
 5 - five  |      2
 5 - five  |     10
(15 rows)
```

How should I alter the query to make it work ? I thought about a recursive CTE but couldn't figure out how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original query you break the relationship by doing subqueries. Rewrite it like so:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM jsonb_array_elements('[
  {"first": ["1 - one", "2 - two", "3 - three"], "second": [1, 2]},
  {"first": ["4 - four", "5 - five"], "second": [10]}
]') AS o,
LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(o.value->'first') AS f(first),
LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(o.value->'second') AS s(second)
```

Comment: When I integrated the idea in my query, I got bitten by the `AS o` thinking that the `o` means the name of the table when it means instead the name of the column and could even be written as `AS x(o)` (without added benefit). Thanks for the use of `LATERAL`.

Comment: Well, no. In fact it is the name of the table and the name of the column is `value`. I guess that PosgreSQL handles `value` particularly. Not sure. Tried your query with `AS o(o)`, `AS x(o)` and `AS o(x)` and everything worked.

Comment: `AS o` will generate a table with one column `value` and `o` is the alias of the table (just in case you want to use it further or distinguish from another generated table having the `value` column).

Comment: But then, why don't you need to write `jsonb_array_elements(value->'first')` instead ? Because there is only one column and PostgreSQL is guessing that it is the wanted column (only available choice) ?

Comment: You're right, it should not have worked (or if it works it still requires one to read the documentation). I have made a small correction in the query.